# Detect when Screen (Tab) comes to foreground with Class Component and react-navigation: Lifecycle Functions are not working in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` 6.x and I am lookin for a way to find out, when a Class Component os focussed. Everything I find online/in the documentation is about functional components, using `hooks`, because the normal life cycle functions provided by `react are not working`. So this

```
componentDidMount () { ..... }
```

does not work either. However, I need to call a function every time the component is focussed.
How to find out, if a Class Component comes into focus using `react-navigation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way you can actually use the hook in your class component. You will need to wrap your class component with a wrapper that contains the focus hook. Example taken from the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused).

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Get it from props
    const { isFocused } = this.props;
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return <Profile {...props} isFocused={isFocused} />;
}
```